# Stop a tween animation in tween.js and three.js

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I'm having trouble stopping a tween in three.js, using tween.js.
The docs state to use `tween.stop()`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/feLzjzy9/1/

As you hover with the mouse over a box, it starts to change color. This animation takes 10 seconds, but I try to stop it just to test the .stop() feature using `setTimeout(function(){ tween.stop() }, 1000);`but it doesn't do a thing...

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: did you start your tween? i don't see tween update function in animate().
You also can call TWEEN.getAll() in console to check if is your tween works properly.

Comment: In my project there's a `tween.update(time)` in the animate() function. In the jsfiddle it's apparently on line 144. I tried using `console.log(TWEEN.getAll())`. After I call `tween.stop()`, my console outputs `[ ]` , so I guess the tween is stopped, but the animation (=changing color) keeps going.

Comment: It is possible that animation is result of another action than a tween?

Comment: Try to use more specific reference for a tween. stopping the tween will keep tween at the reference, another action did start the same tween again. after stopping use TWEEN.remove(tween);

Comment: (comment to your first 2nd reponse): Don't think so... I included tween.js for this animation only. Also, in the jsfiddle (i.e. a completely different project), .stop() doesn't seem to work either on color-change animations.

Comment: I don't think the tween is started somewhere else, since the .start() is inside a function which is only called once (on startup). The console confirms that function is only called once.

Comment: You referencing tween var in each mouse intersection. That does not automatically mean, that TWEEN animation will not be removed after rereferencing tween var to another  animation. That means tween var is not referencing TWEEN object animation, when you call stop() on this var.
In the same time, TWEEN must be updated even if it is not visible, to be stopped. You updating TWEEN object only when your intersection is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Reference problem and update problem.
I made some changes in you code. It is not a solution, you can use each change individually.
Best solution is to make each tween as var inside a function, integrate counting in tweened objects and use onUpdate(function(){if(this.counter > 1000){tween.stop}}) (INTERSECTED.material.color) because  you creating a lot of unrefferenced timers and tweens, which will be a performance problem.

```
function animate() { 
      //
      TWEEN.update();
      //
}

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        if (INTERSECTED != intersects[0].object) {

            if (INTERSECTED) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);

            INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
            INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
            //INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex(0xff0000);
            TWEEN.remove(tween);
            tween = new TWEEN.Tween(INTERSECTED.material.color).onStart(function(){

      setTimeout(function(){ tween.stop() }, 1000); ///not good
}).start();     
            .to({r: 0, g: 25, b: 155}, 10000) /// here set correct time
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quartic.In)
            .start();

            setTimeout(function(){ tween.stop() }, 1000);/// will not work if you create anoter it that one second

        }
        else {
            if(tween) tween.update(time); // bad
        }

    }
```

Comment: `function animate() { 
      //
      TWEEN.update();
      //
}` , did it! Thanks! Before, I was using `function animate() { 
      //
      tween.update(time)      //
`}

Comment: those are 2 different things, tween is your var, TWEEN is a global object for tween.js functions.